# python pyparsing "^" vs "|" keywords

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have a small testcase created to illustrate a problem I am seeing with the "^" operator. When I try and use the ^ operator instead of the | operator below, I get an error.

**Edit:** Just to make the question clearer (although it has already been answered) for anyone else reading it. The question is why can I not use the "^" operator in place of the "|" operator in the following program.

The testcase:

```
import unittest
import pyparsing as pp

def _get_verilog_num_parse():
    """Get a parser that can read a verilog number
    return: Parser for verilog numbers
    rtype: PyParsing parser object
    """
    apos           = pp.Suppress(pp.Literal("'"))
    radix          = pp.Word('bdhBDH', exact=1).setResultsName('radix')
    dec_num        = pp.Word(pp.nums+'_'   ).setParseAction(lambda x:int(x[0].replace('_', ''),10))
    hex_num        = pp.Word(pp.hexnums+'_').setParseAction(lambda x:int(x[0].replace('_', ''),16))
    bin_num        = pp.Word('01'+'_'      ).setParseAction(lambda x:int(x[0].replace('_', ''),2))
    size           = pp.Optional(dec_num).setResultsName('size')
    valid_nums     = {'b':bin_num,'d':dec_num,'h':hex_num}
    verilog_lits   = pp.Forward()

    def size_mask(parser):
        size = parser.get('size')
        if size is not None:
            print("In size_mask. size: {} parser[value]: {}".format(size, parser['value']))
            return parser['value'] & ((1<<size) -1)
        else:
            print("In size_mask. no size. parser[value]: {}".format(parser['value']))
            return parser['value']

    def radix_parse_action(toks):
        verilog_lits << (valid_nums[toks.get('radix').lower()])
    radix.addParseAction(radix_parse_action)
    #return size, apos + radix + verilog_lits
    return (size + apos + radix + verilog_lits.setResultsName('value')).addParseAction(size_mask)

class CheckPyParsing(unittest.TestCase):
    '''Check that the Expression Parser works with the expressions
    defined in this test'''

    def test_or(self):
        """Check basic expressions not involving referenced parameters"""
        expressions_to_test = [
                ("8'd255",255),
                ("'d255",255),
                ]
        parser = _get_verilog_num_parse() | pp.Literal("Some_demo_literal")
        for expr,expected in expressions_to_test:
            result = parser.parseString(expr)
            print("result: {}, val: {}".format(result, result[0]))
            self.assertEqual(expected,result[0], "test_string: {} expected: {} result: {}".format(expr, expected, result[0]))
```

When I use the | I get this:

```
test_or (yoda_interface.tests.CheckPyParsing_test.CheckPyParsing)
Check basic expressions not involving referenced parameters ... In size_mask. size: 8 parser[value]: 255
result: [255], val: 255
In size_mask. no size. parser[value]: 255
result: [255], val: 255
ok
```

When I use the ^ I get:

```
test_or (yoda_interface.tests.CheckPyParsing_test.CheckPyParsing)
Check basic expressions not involving referenced parameters ... ERROR

======================================================================
ERROR: test_or (yoda_interface.tests.CheckPyParsing_test.CheckPyParsing)
Check basic expressions not involving referenced parameters
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\projects\check_private\yoda_interface\tests\CheckPyParsing_test.py", line 45, in test_or
    result = parser.parseString(expr)
  File "C:\Users\gkuhn\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 1125, in parseString
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\gkuhn\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 1115, in parseString
    loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )
  File "C:\Users\gkuhn\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 989, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "C:\Users\gkuhn\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 2440, in parseImpl
    raise maxException
pyparsing.ParseException:  (at char 3), (line:1, col:4)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.012s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: Or and MatchFirst are different (see e.g. http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/HowToUsePyparsing#toc7), what were you expecting?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - it is true that they are different, but they way they are used in this test, they should both give the same result. By adding an impossible case for the second alternative (as the OP does in his test), both '^' and '|' should behave the same.

Comment: I think this is a good question. The poster has identified an unintuitive side-effect from using the different flavors of alternative matching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a difficult case, and it requires a little understanding of some of pyparsing's internals to refactor your parser into a working version.

Your "perfect storm" of problems combines these factors:

- a dynamic parser element (`verilog_lits`)
- a parse action that dynamically defines the contents of a related parser element
- attaching that parse action to an element in an `Or` expression

`MatchFirst` (created using the '|' operator), can just crunch through its list of alternatives trying to parse each in turn, and returning when one succeeds. In doing so, if there is a parse action, then after the parse succeeds, the parse action gets run, as expected. In your case, this parse action injects the correct numeric expression for the value part of the binary, hex, or decimal value.

But `Or` can't follow this same strategy. When writing pyparsing, I could not predict if any given parse action has side effects or other implications besides working just with the parsed tokens. So when `Or` goes through its alternatives, looking for the *longest* match, it has to do so *without* calling parse actions. If there is a parse action that updates a dynamic element in the parser, that action won't be called until the successful alternative is selected. Since you rely on the parse action to complete the parser, this will fail if the trigger that defines the dynamic expression is part of an `Or`.

Based on this, I refactored your definition of "a radix followed by its type-specific allowed value" by replacing:

```
return (size + apos + radix + verilog_lits.setResultsName('value')).addParseAction(size_mask)
```

with

```
radix_int = pp.ungroup(pp.CaselessLiteral('d').suppress() + dec_num |
                       pp.CaselessLiteral('h').suppress() + hex_num |
                       pp.CaselessLiteral('b').suppress() + bin_num)
return (size + apos + radix_int('value')).addParseAction(size_mask)
```

This may not have the pizzazz of a dynamic subexpression, but by expanding the dynamic expression into a set of 3 specific alternatives, this expression is now safe to be included into a "evaluate all and choose the longest" `Or` expression.

Comment: Hi Paul, firstly thank you for spending so much time on this answer.. This issue was killing me yesterday. This is my first foray into using (and understanding) a parser and yours is great. Can you recommend to me a good source of documentation for pyparsing? I'll admit I'm going about pyparsing's usage in a very cowboy fashion at the moment. Finally, your refactoring also looks like it may be more efficient. My use of the "pizzazz" is again due to my fumbling/learning with your tool :)

Comment: Another question please, why do you use pp.ungroup() in your solution? What does ungroup do here? I tried your solution with and without it and they both work... well to be honest, I haven't tried reintegrating your solution in with my finished parser, perhaps the answer is in that.

Comment: I just assumed ungroup would be required, as I've had issues in the past with extra nested levels when building an And expression with '+', even if one of the two terms is suppressed. For more doc links, visit this page at the pyparsing wiki: http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/Documentation

Comment: Ha! An even simpler solution: I don't even remember implementing this feature, but I guess I have run into this before. There is an optional keyword argument to `setParseAction()`, `callDuringTry` specifically to handle this case. In your original code, you could simply write `radix.addParseAction(radix_parse_action, callDuringTry=True)`, which as the keyword implies, will call the parse action even during the first phase of the Or processing. You just have to take care that a parse action like this will have no side effects.